# Unwinding Segue results in Clear Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view controllers, connect view a show (push) segue. In the initial view controller I have the following to control the style of the navigation bar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 18)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB("292929")]
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB("f7f7f7")
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("E9E9E9").CGColor
}
```

In the destination view controller, I have the following to control the style of the navigation bar in that controller:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 18)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB("FFFFFF")]

}
```

The issue is when I click the back button on the destination view controller to return to the initial view controller, the navigation bar is set to the style of the destination view controller. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write code for navigation bar styling in viewWillAppear method for both controllers as below.
Because viewDidLoad method is called once per lifetime of view.Once the view is loaded this method won't be executed again. so instead of viewDidLoad we have to use **viewWillAppear**

**Initialview controller code**

```
override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 18)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB("292929")]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB("f7f7f7")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("E9E9E9").CGColor
}
```

**Destination view controller code**

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 18)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB("FFFFFF")]
}
```